# Account detail page not showing Copy Billing Address to Shipping AddressAddress Information link in Ligthning

Tags: lightning, account, detail-page

On Salesforce classic view the "Copy Billing Address to Shipping AddressAddress Information" link is displaying on address details section on Account object. But when I switch to lightning, it disappears.

Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowledge article: [`How to show the Copy Billing Address to Shipping Address link when editing Contact or Account records?`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240508&type=1) says:

> This is only applicable in Classic User Interface and **not in Lightning Experience**.

You would have to build your own if its critical for business or wait unless salesforce implements it.